# Wordpress - How to create new post from form without admin review?

Tags: wordpress, roles, user-permissions, article

I have a website built with Wordpress, where users  can sign in and post articles in their dedicated  pages. They can create new articles compiling a form  into the website. The article  will be  visible  in their own page after the admin (me) approved it. Well, I want to skip this step and make  users  able  to publish new articles without admin review. Is there a plugin that can do that? I'm new to Wordpress, so every help will be  greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes- most of the user-submission plugins I've seen have that option. This one, for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/ has an option to publish user submissions immediately.